# Improving the query processing performance of SUM and JOIN SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

```
SELECT SUM(C_QUANTITY)
FROM CARS JOIN ORDERS
ON C_ORDERKEY = O_ORDERKEY;
```

I have this query that aggregate sum of L_QUANTITY from the JOIN tables. The query cost, by using `EXPLAIN PLAN` is `12147`. The objective is to improve this `SELECT` statement by implementing a more efficient `SELECT` statement that will get the same result.

I have tried

```
SELECT SUM(C_QUANTITY)
FROM CARS
```

It returned the same result but the query cost is *exactly the same* as the original. I thought that by removing the `JOIN`, the `SELECT` query will improve.

*Is there a way to reduce the cost by simply modify the `SELECT` statement only?*

Edit:

Original query plan

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                               
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2287326370                                                     
                                                                                
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
| Id  | Operation          | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |          |     1 |     3 | 12147   (1)| 00:00:01 | 
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |          |     1 |     3 |            |          | 
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL|   CARS   |  1800K|  5273K| 12147   (1)| 00:00:01 | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

9 rows selected.
```

With the second query

```
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                               
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2287326370                                                     
                                                                                
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
| Id  | Operation          | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |          |     1 |     3 | 12147   (1)| 00:00:01 | 
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |          |     1 |     3 |            |          | 
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL|   CARS   |  1800K|  5273K| 12147   (1)| 00:00:01 | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

9 rows selected.
```

Comment: I agree this is weird. The first query is of course much more complex than the second one. Are you sure you have not been mistaken? (The query or data model seem weird too, by the way. A car has a quantity and each order orders that quantity, so you multiply a car's quantity by the number of its orders? Really?)

Comment: HI Thorsten, thanks for the reply. The semantics was changed from the original perhaps that is why you find the data model weird. I am not mistaken in both the query processing - I have ran it a few times and the results are the same. Thus, posting this question here in SO hoping to get some feedback.

Comment: The explain plans look identical to me.  The performance between the two queries may not be identical, but just very close.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I think improving for the above queries with just modification of `SELECT` is not possible. I will mark your answer as the right one since `index` does indeed improve such query.

Comment: It took me some time to understand this. The order table is the parent table. A car is always part of one order. In order hence to sum up car quantities, Oracle doesn't have to read the orders table. All information needed is in the cars table. So the optimizer decides not to read the orders table at all. This is good and hence the best plan anyway. Your queries are as simple as possible and cannot be optimized. With an index contaning the quantity, Oracle can decide to make a full index scan instead of reading the table, so as to read less drive sectors/blocks.

Comment: A lower estimated cost is probably a good thing, but I wouldn't rely on it always meaning that the plan is more efficient. Personally I never bother looking at the cost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest adding the following index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON ORDERS (O_ORDERKEY, C_QUANTITY);
```

Presumably, the `ORDERS` table would be much larger than `CARS`.  If so, Oracle would likely satisfy the query by scanning `CARS` and then would be able to use the above index to lookup in the `ORDERS` table.  I add the `C_QUANTITY` column to the end of the index, to cover the summation in the select clause.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I understand that adding `index` can definitely speed up the query but is it possible to do it *without*?

Comment: I have included the explain plans in my edits. Just thinking out loud, could it be due to my machine and hence both query are giving me the same cost?

Comment: I don't think there is a c_quantity column in the orders table. The only reasonable (?) index I can think of speeding those queries is `create index idx on cars (c_quantity)` where the DBMS *might* decide for a full index scan to save some disk reading.

Answer (score 4):

If you have two table `cars` and `orders`that are not connected, you will get and *ordinary* join execution plan as follows.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation           | Name   | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |        |     1 |    15 |       |   297   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE     |        |     1 |    15 |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN         |        |   100K|  1464K|  1664K|   297   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| ORDERS |   100K|   488K|       |    47   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL| CARS   |   100K|   976K|       |    62   (2)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - access("C_ORDERKEY"="O_ORDERKEY")
```

The table `cars` is apparently a *child* table or the `orders`, i.e. you have this constraints

```
alter table orders add primary key (O_ORDERKEY);
alter table cars add constraint cars_fk foreign key(C_ORDERKEY) references orders(O_ORDERKEY);
```

Oracle is *smart* enough to know it does not need to access the `orders`  table to get the sum

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |      |     1 |    10 |    63   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE    |      |     1 |    10 |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| CARS |   100K|   976K|    63   (4)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - filter("C_ORDERKEY" IS NOT NULL)
```

Note the filter `C_ORDERKEY IS NOT NULL` which is still required to get the right sum if the column `C_ORDERKEY` is nullable. (Those rows would be eliminated in the join).

In case it is not, which may be meaningfull

```
 alter table cars modify C_ORDERKEY not null;
```

you only need to define an index on the `C_QUANTITY` column to get the optimal plan

```
create index car_idx on cars(C_QUANTITY);

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation             | Name    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT      |         |     1 |     5 |    63   (2)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE       |         |     1 |     5 |            |          |
|   2 |   INDEX FAST FULL SCAN| CAR_IDX |   100K|   488K|    63   (2)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note that the `INDEX FAST FULL SCAN` uses the index in a kind as a table full scan access (i.e. without direct accessing the index block using the pointers) so it is (in case that the index is smaller than the table) much faster that the table full scan access.

Comment: You don’t need the `not null` constraint, instead you can add it to the query as a filter because the `null` values won’t be contributing to the `sum` anyway

Comment: I did not catch it @AndrewSayer - the `not null` constraint is on `C_ORDERKEY`  not on the `C_QUANTITY`.  Of course you can add `where C_ORDERKEY is not null` to the query with the same effect...

Comment: Ah, I read too fast and was assuming you were creating the constraint so that the index could be used instead of the table scan. It seems Oracle is smart enough to know it only cares about `not null` values for `sum` on its own then.

Comment: Well the real problem is with rows with `C_ORDERKEY is null` and  `C_QUANTITY is not null` those values *must be excluded from the SUM* as they would be discarded in the join (that is not performed) @AndrewSayer